# How to translate timestamp_ms to regular time stamp?

Tags: json

I'm pretty dumb when it comes to anything like this and someone I know asked how to translate this: "timestamp_ms": 1606291977223, to a regular time, anybody know how?

EDIT: I found a converter online lol, why didn't I try that sooner :')
(https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the JSON from JavaScript, you can send the timestamp_ms property to the Date object in the below way which will provide the time in regular time format.
Sample code,

```
var ms = new Date().getTime(); //1608795435606
console.log(new Date(ms)); //Thu Dec 24 2020 13:07:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```